# Spring boot 2 IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I am trying to establish 2 database connections in spring boot 2 app. I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
```

Here is my configuration on Primary db

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"com.cmp.myapp.repository"})
 public class PrimDBConfig {

@Primary
@Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "primdb")
@Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.cmp.myapp.dto")
            .persistenceUnit("primdb")
            .build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("myEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
}
```

Here is the secondary db connection

```
@Configuration
public class SecDBConfig {

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Bean(name = "secDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary.datasource")
public DataSource wiseDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("secondary.datasource.jdbc-url"));
    ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("secondary.datasource.driverClassName"));
    ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("secondary.datasource.username"));
    ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("secondary.datasource.password"));
    return ds;
}
}
```

My application.properties file as below:

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.validation-query=select 1
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true

secondary.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:as400://xxxxxx;
secondary.datasource.driverClassName=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
secondary.datasource.username=xxxxx
secondary.datasource.password=xxxxxx
secondary.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
secondary.datasource.validation-query=select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

May I know what I'm doing wrong here, please advice. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons I can think of is, you have added this prefix

```
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary.datasource")
```

Then accessing driverClassName using complete path

```
ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("secondary.datasource.driverClassName"));
```

I think you should remove the prefix and try accessing.
This blog may also help you. https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/

Comment: I noticed env properties was returning null, but when I hard coded the values it was still giving the same error. It worked when I tried your way of doing it through your blog, thank you for that- really appreciated                                                 
But not sure whats the real issue in the way I was doing!